# image click on mobile inside the sheets app

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a custom script that runs when i click an image i insert in a google spreadsheet ... everything is working on non-touch devices ... but on mobile, inside the sheets app, it does no trigger the function ... it just selects the image

am i doing anything wrong here?
are google script supposed to work inside the sheets app? if not i really do no see the point of using them

link is not the solution, custom menus also do not appear on the sheets app ... i am literally left without any idea to try out

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Google Apps Script runs only on Desktop computer and that too only when Script is allowed to run on your browser. For most part Google Apps Script is same as JavaScript. I have tried to run them on Android phones but without any success.